# C# Attribute check is an value equals the constructor argument and get constructor values

Tags: c#, constructor, attributes, equals, system.reflection

How can i check that some string is equal to the "constructor" arguments of an attribute?
And how to get all constructor values (TestArg1, TestArg2)?

```
struct MyData
{
    [MyAttr("TestArg1", "TestArg2")] //check that some string equals TestArg1/TestArg2
    public string TestArg;
}
```

Comment: what is "some string"? Which string do you want to check? `TestArg`? Or any diffrerent one?

Comment: @HimBromBeere any different one. Do you know how get all constructor agruments (TestArg1, TestArg2..)?

Comment: You would have to write manual code to check this, nothing can do it automatically, at least without using some sort of AOP style tool like Fody. But honestly, this looks like an XY problem, why would you even want to do this?

Comment: @DavidG oh , ok thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck? Currently this question is pretty broad. I would suggest to look for how to get a custom attribute on a member,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This primarily depends on what attribute you're looking at and how it's coded.   See the code below as an example on how to do what you're asking.

```
//The attribute we're looking at
public class MyAtt : System.Attribute
{
    public string name;
    public string anotherstring;

    public MyAtt(string name, string anotherstring)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.anotherstring = anotherstring;
    }
}

public static class Usage
{
    [MyAtt("String1", "String2")] //Using the attribute
    public static string SomeProperty = "String1";
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsEqualToAttribute("String1"));
        Console.WriteLine(IsEqualToAttribute("blah"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static bool IsEqualToAttribute(string mystring)
    {
        //Let's get all the properties from Usage
        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(Usage).GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            //Let's make sure we have the right property
            if (prop.Name == "SomeProperty")
            {
                //Get the attributes from the property
                var attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes();

                //Select just the attribute named "MyAtt"
                var attr = attrs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.GetType().Name == "MyAtt");
                MyAtt myAttribute = attr as MyAtt; //Just casting to the correct type
                if (myAttribute.name == mystring) //Compare the strings
                    return true;
                if (myAttribute.anotherstring == mystring) //Compare the strings
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see we get the attribute off the property using reflection and then just compare the properties.

More info can be found here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/accessing-attributes-by-using-reflection

As far as getting the constructor properties something along the lines of

```
typeof(MyAtt).GetConstructor().GetParameters()
```

Would retrieve the parameter details for the constructor.

There is also info on this in the Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributedata.constructor?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you are asking for, but it's not particularly scaleable and requires a bunch of manual code to get working but may get you on the road to what you are trying to achieve. Assuming we have an attribute something like this that takes a string array in it's constructor:

```
public class MyAttrAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string[] AllowedValues { get; }
    public MyAttrAttribute(params string[] values)
    {
        AllowedValues = values;
    }
}
```

You can change your field to be a property with a backing field. This allows you to override the `set` method and do your checking in there:

```
private string _testArg;

[MyAttr("TestArg1", "TestArg2")] //check that some string equals TestArg1/TestArg2
public string TestArg
{
    get => _testArg;

    set
    {
        var allowedValues = this.GetType() //Get the type of 'this'
            .GetProperty(nameof(TestArg)) // Get this property
            .GetCustomAttribute<MyAttrAttribute>() // Get the attribute
            .AllowedValues; //Get the allowed values specified in the attribute

        if(!allowedValues.Contains(value))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), 
                $"The value '{value}' is not allowed");
        }
        _testArg = value;
    }
}
```

Having said all of this, I firmly believe that there is a better way to achieve what you are asking. For example, if you are restricted to a minimal set of values, then an `enum` would almost certainly be a better option than a string.